# JQuery - Change color of division row on onchange event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement where i have to change the color of the `row` based on the `onchange` value in a dropdown. I have `rows` that are in the form of `division`. There are two main `divisions` which have rows in the form of division which were earlier two main `tables`.

Now when i change the value in the `combo` of a `row` in first `division` i want to change the `color` of the entire `division` `row`. Also with that i want to change the `color` of the `row` in the second main `division` as well. I could easily do it with `tables` but with `division` i am finding it difficult and also i am not sure about feasibility. Below is my code structure and my `JQuery` which i used for changing color.

```js
$('#bodyLeft tr').bind('click', function(e) {
  var bodyLeftTable = $("#bodyLeft tr").index(this);
  var vehicleClassVal = $("#bodyLeft tr:nth-child(" + bodyLeftTable + ")").find('.vehicleClass').val();
  if (scheduleStatusVal == 'Volvo') {
    $("#bodyLeft tr:nth-child(" + bodyLeftTable + ")").addClass("runningVehicleClass");
    $("#bodyRight tr:nth-child(" + bodyLeftTable + ")").addClass("runningVehicleClass");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--First Division-->
<div id="bodyLeft">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <select class="vehicleClass">
                  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <input type="text" name="address">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth" style="white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="text" name="pass">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <select class="vehicleClass">
                  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <input type="text" name="address">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth" style="white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="text" name="pass">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Second Division -->
<div id="bodyRight">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell width20">
      <input type="text" name="parts">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell width85">
      <input type="text" name="ischecked">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell width85" style="white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="text" name="validity">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <input type="text" name="parts">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <input type="text" name="ischecked">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth" style="white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="text" name="validity">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to update the jQuery selectors to match the elements you changed. `$('#bodyLeft tr')` becomes `$('#bodyLeft .divTableRow')` etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, `#bodyLeft tr` targets what exactly?

I can's see a `tr` anywhere in there.

I am assuming you need to bind click to `#bodyLeft.vehicleClass`?
In your JS code, check every selector and make it match the structure in the HTML.

Or post a relevant code of a table where it should target.

EDIT: I just read text again and noticed **you used to use table**. Yeah, definitely **rewrite your query selectors**. Both in JS you posted and in other code and don't forget to check CSS as well while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

Following could be one of the solution following your approach.

```js
$('#bodyLeft .divTableRow').bind('click', function(e) {
 
  var curRow, curSelect, nextRow, nextSelect;
  
  curRow = $( this );
  
  curSelect = curRow.find('select.vehicleClass');
  
  nextRow = curRow.next();
  
  nextSelect = nextRow.find('select.vehicleClass');
  
 // Following are sample stuff
  // replace with your actual stuff
  curRow.css('background-color', 'yellow');
  curSelect.css('background-color', 'yellow');
 nextRow.css('background-color', 'cyan');  
  nextSelect.css('background-color', 'cyan');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bodyLeft">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <select class="vehicleClass">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <input type="text" name="address">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth" style="white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="text" name="pass">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <select class="vehicleClass">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <input type="text" name="address">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth" style="white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="text" name="pass">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Second Division -->
<div id="bodyRight">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell width20">
      <input type="text" name="parts">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell width85">
      <input type="text" name="ischecked">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell width85" style="white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="text" name="validity">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <input type="text" name="parts">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth">
      <input type="text" name="ischecked">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell divWidth" style="white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="text" name="validity">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```